# How to delete records in a different model in Odoo

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-15

I have added a Boolean attribute to res_config_settings. When the Boolean is False I want to delete all records in a custom Model ('my.device').

I have tried three different approaches:

1.In `res_config_settings`:

```
devices = self.env['my.device'].browse()
devices.unlink()
```

2. also in `res_config_settings`:

```
devices = self.env['my.device'].browse()
for d in devices:
    d.unlink()
```

3. in `my.device` model

```
def unlink_all(self):
    for rec in self:
        rec.unlink()
```

Then call `self.env['pushbullet.device'].unlink_all()` from `res_config_settings`.
None of the options work but strangely, the first time I tried Option 1, all but one record was deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on two special factors: security and active mechanism. To really delete everything use `sudo()` to act as superuser and `.with_context(active_test=False)` to also find inactive records.

Example:

```py
self.env['my.device'].sudo().with_context(active_test=False).search([]).unlink()
```

Or maybe more readable:

```py
device_sudo = self.env['my.device'].sudo()
all_devices = device_sudo.with_context(active_test=False).search([])
all_devices.unlink()
```

If you don't want to bypass security/access rules, just remove the `sudo` parts.